# jQuery return all matched element, need to way to determine selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, element

Please help to determine the element.

Please check my example http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/DFd7e/

I want to get return from all `li` after 2nd level but only selected one.

in css it should be `ul ul li`.

My problem is if I write above way, jquery will return all matched element not only the one I chooses.

Either `$('#A').find('ul ul li')` or `$('#A ul ul li')` are the same result.

Usually `$(this)` will be the chosen element, but I dont know why it doesnt work in this case.

Thank you very much for your advice and help.

Comment: select only 2nd level ? ul > li

Comment: Just tired, same result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to stop propagation of the event up to its ancestors.

```
$('#A').find('ul ul li').click(function(e){ 
    alert($(this).html());
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

[`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/DFd7e/3/